# What is a good practice to follow when importing libraries/packages in python when it's not global?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm creating objects by composition. So

```
class OMX:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class PYG:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class AudioPlayer:
    def __init__(self):
        audioController = None
        if someCondition:
            audioController = OMX()
        else:
            audioController = PYG()
```

OMX requires `import subprocess`, but PYG does not. So I don't want to unnecessarily put a global `import subprocess`. So I was considering putting the import in the `__init__` of OMX like this:

```
class OMX:
    def __init__(self):
        import subprocess
```

Is this good practice in Python?

Comment: Omitting the line `audioController = None` would be more Pythonic.

Comment: "OMX requires import subprocess, but PYG does not. So I don't want to unnecessarily put a global import subprocess." Why?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: The code is just an example. `PYG` could very well have its own imports. The point is that PYG does not require importing `subprocess`. Importing unnecessary packages takes up extra memory.

Comment: @Nav probably not subprocess. It may already be loaded when the interpreter starts. In any case, it would be almost entirely negligible, are you on some limited system? In any case, you *can* do what you stated, although, do the import in the function where you use `subprocess`, because the name will only be local. But it makes your code confusing for negligible benefits.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: `subprocess` is just an example. I'm asking about any `import`. So the only solution would be to create a separate package for OMX and a separate one for PYG and do the import at the top of the file in those package?

Comment: @Nav that's *one* solution, the other solution is the one you have already, but again, you have to do the import in the method you actually use subprocess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PEP 8 has [this to say](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.

More practically, you should consider that importing something in a constructor does not automatically make it available to methods.

Comment: So the only solution would be to create a separate package for OMX and a separate one for PYG and do the import at the top of the file in those packages?

Comment: Presumably you'd end up importing both of these in the module containing AudioPlayer, so I'm not sure you'd save anything.